# Algebraic solution for a system of algebraic equations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, algebraic-equations

I was asked about solving algebraically the following system of algebraic equations.
$$f(a,b):=a(1-b)+ab\frac a{a+b}.$$
$$u = f(a,b),\quad v = f(b,a).$$
Solve algebraically $(a,b)$ in terms of $(u,v)$

---

Multiplying both sides of the equations by $a+b$ would give us a system of cubic equations.

Comment: Is this $$b(1-a)+\frac{ab^2}{a+b}=v$$ and $$a(1-b)+\frac{a^2b}{a+b}=u$$?

Answer (score 0):

After multiplying by $$a+b\neq 0$$ we get
$$a^2+ab-ab^2=u(a+b)$$
$$b^2-a^2b+ab=v(a+b)$$

Comment: I think if you go for $au+bv$ and $bu-av$ you can cancel the $a+b$ factor and get a solvable system.

Comment: @MarkBennet: I do not see how $au+bv$ looses the $(a+b)$ factor. It is still there. How would you solve the equations?

Comment: @Hans Apologies I got a sign wrong - I meant $au-bv$. And there is work still to do.

Comment: Dr. Sonnhard Graubner, is this your solution? Are you working on it?

Answer (score 0):

This is [answered](https://mathoverflow.net/a/342849/32660) with the aide of a Computer Algebraic System (Mathematica or Maple) on Mathoverflow.net after I [cross-posted](https://mathoverflow.net/q/342824/32660) the question there.